# Using $\varphi \Rightarrow \psi \equiv \sim \varphi \vee \psi$ in proof writing

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm currently studding logic and I learned that, if $\varphi,\psi$ are two propositional formulas, then:

$$\varphi \Rightarrow \psi \equiv \sim \varphi \vee \psi$$

And I was wondering, does that mean that, for example, if we want to prove that: "If $(a,b)$ is a maximum of $f$, then $\nabla f(a,b)=0$", is the same as proving: "$(a,b)$ is not a maximum of $f$ or $\nabla f(a,b)$ = 0"? Can we use this formulas when doing proofs?

Comment: The equivalence holds and thus you can "swap" between the two's in every case this can be useful.

Comment: Silly example with *natural* numbers: "either $n=0$ or $n > 0$" is the same as: "if $n \ne 0$, then $n > 0$"